# Set alternative palette to default theme in native base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want to set a default theme in Native Base, and have seen a lot of links to official [customisation docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/customizingComponents#theaming-nb-headref) and the [nativebase customiser](https://nativebase.io/customizer). But they're all dead.

Native Base already provides a [default theme](https://docs.nativebase.io/default-theme) with a bunch of colours. When you launch an app, by default it seems to have the cyan colour palette. All I want to do is switch from `cyan` to one of their other colour swatches, so that by default all the colours come from, say, `amber`.

I know there's the option to set default colours with `extendTheme` -- is that the only option? Extend the theme and manually add in all the hex codes I want? Or can I just set the theme to `amber` somewhere and all the colours will be applied?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue i wanted to be able to create a primary theme colors and switch the theme without typing out all the colors so far this solution is working for me to select colors from the existing default theme.

```js
const {colors} = extendTheme(colors);
const currentColor = colors.green;

const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    // Add new color
    primary: currentColor,
  },
  config: {
    // Changing initialColorMode to 'dark
    useSystemColorMode: false,
    initialColorMode: 'dark',
  },
});

export default function App() {
  return (
   <NativeBaseProvider theme={theme}>
     <NavigationContainer>
       <App />
     </NavigationContainer>
   </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the default color is primary.600.

This is the color that inputs will default to when you select them, or that a custom switch will default to.

So this is the specific color you should override to change the theme default.

(There may be others, but this is what I've found so far)